# Get balances of list of address every X minutes

Tags: ethers.js

I have a list of addresses where I have to check the balance of ETH and Tokens every X minutes, so I can update balances on a DB. What is the best way to do this using Node.js?

Comment: There is Openzeppelin Defender with Sentinel and Autotasks https://docs.openzeppelin.com/defender/

Answer (score 1):

Theres a ton of articles on how to do this.  But here is som rough code, you'll need to swap the address and the network depending on what network etc

```
function GetBalances() {
    const ethers = require('ethers')
    const network = 'rinkeby' // use rinkeby testnet
    const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider(network)
    const address = '0xF02c1c8e6114b1Dbe8937a39260b5b0a374432bB'
    provider.getBalance(address).then((balance) => {
     // convert a currency unit from wei to ether
     const balanceInEth = ethers.utils.formatEther(balance)
     console.log(`balance: ${balanceInEth} ETH`)
    })
}
```

As For getting the ERC-20 token balances you can just use the ERC20 interface to get the token balance

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const rpcURL = 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/xxxx'
const web3 = new Web3(rpcURL)

let tokenAddress = "0x20fe562d797a42dcb3399062ae9546cd06f63280";
let walletAddress = "0xdD440e8eCA5F1F3e6D5ffE903148EFB374942df2";

// The minimum ABI to get ERC20 Token balance
let minABI = [
  // balanceOf
  {
    "constant":true,
    "inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],
    "name":"balanceOf",
    "outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],
    "type":"function"
  },
  // decimals
  {
    "constant":true,
    "inputs":[],
    "name":"decimals",
    "outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],
    "type":"function"
  }
];

let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(minABI,tokenAddress);
async function getBalance() {
  balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call();
  return balance;
}

console.log(getBalance());
```

put that in a function and call `setInterval(GetBalances, 10*60*1000)`

Comment: I'm trying to gain priviledges in this community if this answer helps please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies but you need to be a bit more specific with "Tokens", since there are at least 2 kinds I work with here is my longshot:

1. Verify NonFungibleTokens
2. Verify ERC20 tokens

There are RPC providers that have a few really useful apis, one of my favorites is [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/), it provides a really biig free tier in terms of api calls & rpc calls and if you're backend dev you definitely should look at it;

To get the balances of NFT in a wallet i'd use [getnfts](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/getnfts) api; which returns all the NFT (and balances) of a given address;

If you want to check the ERC20 token balances of an address the you could call this one; [getTokenBalances](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/alchemy-gettokenbalances) which returns an array of the balances of all the tokens within a wallet

To check ethereum balance you can call this one: [getBalance](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/eth-getbalance)

Comment: sorry i forgot to add.. xD since you're using node's you could just program an event to call all these apis on a X amount of time :D